# Is it a good practise to initiate one object per all page tests?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm using Selenium with Page Object Pattern. I've got a question about creating objects of page object classes.

Which option is better:

```
@BeforeTest
public void browser() throws IOException {
    driver = initializeBrowser();
    loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
}
```

and using it like this:

```
@Test
public void loginToApp() throws InterruptedException {
    loginPage.clickLoginButton();
    Assert.assertTrue("some assertion");
}

@Test
public void loginToAppUsingLogin() throws IOException {
    loginPage.sendLogin("login");
    loginPage.sendPassword("password");
    loginPage.clickLoginButton();

    Assert.assertTrue("some assertion");
}
```

Or

```
 @BeforeTest
 public void browser() throws IOException {
     driver = initializeBrowser();
 }


 @Test
 public void loginToApp() throws InterruptedException {
     loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
     loginPage.clickLoginButton();
     Assert.assertTrue("some assertion");
 }

 @Test
 public void loginToAppUsingLogin() throws IOException {
     loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
     loginPage.sendLogin("login");
     loginPage.sendPassword("password");
     loginPage.clickLoginButton();

     Assert.assertTrue("some assertion");
 }
```

Are there any contraindications to create one object in @BeforeTest per test suite?

Comment: I'd say this depends on your thing being tested.  Is a `LoginPage` stateful?  I.e. could interactions you make with it in one test mess things up in another test?  If it was me, I wouldn't do it in _either_ of the above ways; I'd just declare it in the field.  `private final LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(this.driver);`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the what the consent is, but the @BeforeTest annotation is used correctly like you did. It initializes your loginPage object before every individual test.

(I'm assuming you use TestNG)

In my experience your first approach is better as it also reduces the amount of repeated code. See [DRY](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: But BeforeTest is called only once. It doesn't behave like @BeforeMethod annotation. So in first case we are creating only one object, in second one 1 object per 1 Test annotation

Comment: Oh then I'm sorry, I confused it with the @Before annotation of JUnit.

Comment: @jamal then you could use the @BeforeMethod annotation and also include the `loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);` statement in the method.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not an answer for my question. I know that I can use it like this. But, is it a good pratice to declare one page object per test suite or it's better to delcare 1 page oject per 1 test or the third option is that it doesn't matter

Comment: Then check the comment from @user2478398 under the original question. I think his answer is correct. The answer is, it depends. If it has state, it should be reset before every test otherwise you can initialize it only once

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think you are splitting hairs here.  For me, I prefer to create a new object *per test* simply because it provides a 'clean' run, i.e., I am not re-using the same instance for a new test.  And to be even more clear/transparent, I clear the cache on the browser each time as well.

Within each test I do this:

```
[Test, Order(10), Description("Navigate to the 'Dashboard' page, click the 'Open' button and fill out the form that loads.")]
public void NavigateToDashboardAndClickElement()
{
   //  Setup a null instance of IE for use in testing.
   IWebDriver driver = null;
   //  Instantiate the IESetupHelper class.
   IESetupHelper setupIE = new IESetupHelper();
   //  Set the environment variables for IE, and launch the browser.
   setupIE.SetupIEVariables(driver);
}
```

And for setting up the browser itself, I do the following:

```
public void SetupIEVariables(IWebDriver driver)
{
   //  Set the options for the driver instance.  In this case, we are ignoring the zoom level of the browswer we are going to use.
   InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions { IgnoreZoomLevel = true };
   //  Clear the broswers cache before launching.
   options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
   //  Create a new driver instance.
   driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"path to driver here", options);
   //  Set the window size for the driver instance to full screen.
   driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
   //  Set the URL for the driver instance to go to.
   driver.Url = @"some URL here";
}
```